# Linux command to compress the most at the expense of being slow

Tags: linux, unix, command, admin

I know there are commands like gzip, bzip, tar, xz. I want to know which command compresses the most to claim more space even at the expense of slower compression time. Any benchmark statistics would be great.

I googled but couldnt find any page which kind of compared it to my needs.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and the answer depends largely on what kind of data you're compressing.

Comment: I am trying to write a script and include this zip command in the program. It may not be exactly program question but I felt its relevant

Answer (score 2):

You can find some (potentailly outdated) benchmarks [here](http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html). In general, `xz -9` is going to compress things pretty well. As others have mentioned, it really depends on what data you're trying to compress, though.

I would recommend giving either bzip or xz a try, and see if they are fast enough and/or compress well enough for your particular application. Benchmarks are never as good as testing them on your exact data set.